# Can a NFC tag communicate with database

Tags: android, database, nfc

For example we have a dataBase on web, in the database are informations about restaurants (text and images). User enter the restaurant and at the table, there is an NFC tag. So the question is can you use this NFC tag to communicate with that database and the android app would download certain informations for restaurant that user is in it. So When user come to different restaurant and place his phone to NFC tag it will download different informations but from same database ? (Or there must be databases for each restaurant?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the app to communicate directly with the database. That poses many security risks and is **very bad practice** What you should do, is build a server that connects to the database, and can serve information about the restaurants.

A database can store any type of information, and multiple databases won't help. One is definitely enough. Note: It's inefficient to store images in databases. You should store the names of the images and store every image as a file on your server.